# I want to detect the first bar has rsi below 70 after the rsi above 70

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

```
//@version=4
study(title="First Bar Below 70 after RSI > 70", shorttitle="First Bar Below 70")

length = input(14, title="RSI Length")
overboughtLevel = input(70, title="Overbought Level")

rsiValue = rsi(close, length)
firstBarBelow70 = 0

if rsiValue > overboughtLevel
    firstBarBelow70 := barssince(rsiValue > overboughtLevel)

plot(firstBarBelow70, color=color.blue, title="First Bar Below 70")
```

but I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: are you trying to get the bar index of that bar?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `firstBarBelow70` variable to return the number of bars since the last occurrence of the `rsiValue > overboughtLevel` condition, you don't need to duplicate it in the local scope, and the `barsince()` call can be moved to the global scope:

```
//@version=4
study(title="First Bar Below 70 after RSI > 70", shorttitle="First Bar Below 70")
length = input(14, title="RSI Length")
overboughtLevel = input(70, title="Overbought Level")
rsiValue = rsi(close, length)
firstBarBelow70 = barssince(rsiValue > overboughtLevel)
plot(firstBarBelow70, color=color.blue, title="First Bar Below 70")
```